# Bind to ListControl without specifying DataTextField and DataValueField?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

Is there a way to bind to an ASP.NET ListControl **without** specifying the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` properties? Maybe some class that will allow the ListControl to infer which property is the text and which the value?

Having to specify these properties every time has lead to typo woes in the past. I think it would help if I could just bind to a collection of the same object type every time and completely ignore the *field* properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do want a control like this, you could extend the `ListBox` class to assume defaults.

Use reflection on the `DataSource` and `GetProperties` of the data type assigned. 
Assume defaults as you like; say the first Property as key(`DataValueField`) and the last as value(`DataTextField`).

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to let it "infer" this automatically.

Imagine you are binding to a collection of `Person`. The Person class may have `Id, Name, Address, City, State, Zip, Email`, and so on. The `ListBox` class cannot read the programmer's mind and decide that he wants to really use `Id` and `Name` for `Value` and `Text` respectively because in many valid scenarios you may really need to display the `Phone` and `Id` instead.

If you at least run the page **once** you'll immediately get an error if you attempt to bind to a non-existing property so this shouldn't be an issue for anybody at all.